# Get contacts from broken iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone

My phone was knocked out of my hand and fell screen side on the ground. I have an off-brand case and my screen will not show anything except for a flash when I press the home button. My phone is currently not connected to an iCloud account and My lock button is broken, how to get my contacts off of my phone?

Comment: Based on your question it seems you don't have a backup? If not, plug your phone into a computer with iTunes installed. If the phone powers in, you should be able to get the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your phone is linked to an iCloud account, try surfing to https://www.icloud.com and login with your credentials.  Once logged in there is a Contacts app which should contain your address book.

If you don't have iCloud you could use iTunes as stated above, but it won't let you access your contacts directly.  Try alternative applications such as Syncios, Appandora or iTools.

If that's not an option you could try to backup your old iPhone with iTunes and restore it to another iPhone.

Another option is to replace the screen and hope for the best.  While repairing a 4S might not make sense, there's cheap refurbished or OEM screens available.  If you don't want to use it afterwards, it till makes a great gift for any kid.  Replacing a screen on a newer iPhone (5 and above) is dirt easy, but replacing one on a 4 or 4S is absolutely not for the faint of heart.

If none of the above work out for you I'm afraid it's a lost case.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to backup my phone because it seems to be the easiest way to go. If all else fails, I'd buy a used phone from eBay and buy a 2G SIM card from http://www.adafruit.com/products/2505.

Comment: Just an extra note.  If you previously haven't connected your iPhone to your iTunes on that very same computer, the iPhone might ask whether it could trust the computer or not.  If that's the case, I hope the touch interface on your broken iPhone still works.  Try simulating it with another iPhone to know exactly where you should touch to indeed trust the computer,

Comment: The touch screen works but it just doesn't light up.